# Yii2 Need explanation for pretty url rules

Tags: yii2, friendly-url, pretty-urls

how can I prettify the following url:

```
group?id=1&page=7&per-page=12
```

to look like group/id/1/page/7/per-page/12

My `UrlManager` currently looks like this:

```
        'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. Add this rule on top of other rules:

```
'<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/page/<page:\d+>/per-page/<per-page:\d+>' => 'site/<action>'
```